# Ubuntu 15.10 - some mouse events register only after movement or 1 second delay

Tags: unity, kubuntu, mouse, 15.10, logitech-unifying

My Logitech wireless mouse behaves oddly with Ubuntu 15.10.

The **mouse scroll** and **left click** event gets registered in the below cases:
- immediately IF moving the mouse (even for one pixel). If not moving the mouse, if gets registered in the following case
- after 1 second of waiting without moving the mouse.

Not every scroll event gets registered immediately. One in 3 scrolls gets delayed (as well as clicks). This happens clearly on web pages, but it is also obvious in tabbed windows with icons on it (found in the settings page of Thunderbird). The issue is more evident with KDE than with Unity.

The issue occurs on Ubuntu 15.10 after the regular updates have been made. I'm not sure if it involves the Intel microcode as well. Tried disabling Intel video driver and it crashed my Desktop Manager (SDDM: black screen upon startup).

My configuration is:

- Lenovo G770 laptop
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4
- Memory: 4GB
- Ubuntu 15.10 - Unity DM
- Graphics: AMD Radeon 6600M and 6700M Series
- Mouse: Logitech M705 wireless mouse with Unifying receiver
- Synaptics touchpad (I think)

Please tell me what else information do i need to post here.

I've used Kubuntu 15.10 (Plasma 5) when I first observed the behavior, then moved to Ubuntu with Unity Desktop, then tried 14.04 LTS. On 14.04 the mouse works fine but I've had an issue with "Wireless and mouse not working after updates", so I installed 15.10 again. Same behavior on Unity 15.10. For the past 4 days, I installed at least 8 times (due to the additional Intel/ATI video issues as well).

I've also tried unloading the mouse kernel module (sudo rmmod psmouse), but it has no effect. I've also tried modifying the mouse parameters in xorg.conf, but to no effect as well.

Please help in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Semi-solution to this issue: Disabling the proprietary ATI drivers and reverting to the default ("X.Org X Server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper...") driver solved the issue. The system and the graphics around the GUI is now much smoother.